# How to plot monthly data having in the x-axis months and Years R studio

Tags: r, plot

I have a dataframe where column 1 are Months, column 2 are Years and column 3 are precipitation values.
I want to plot the precipitation values for EACH month and  EACH year.
My data goes from at January 1961 to February 2019.
¿How can I plot that?
Here is my data:

[image]If I use this:
`plot(YearAn,PPMensual,type="l",col="red",xlab="años", ylab="PP media anual")`

I get this:

[image]

Which is wrong because it puts all the monthly values in every single year! What Im looking for is an x axis that looks like "JAN-1961, FEB1961....until FEB-2019"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done easily using `ggplot`/`tidyverse` packages.

First lets load the the packages (`ggplot` is part of `tidyverse`) and create a sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(month = rep(c(1:12), 2), 
                 year = rep(c("1961", "1962"), 
                            each = 12), 
                 ppmensual = rnorm(24, 5, 2))
```

Now we can plot the data (`df`):

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(month, ppmensual, 
             group = year, 
             color = year)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `lubridate` and `ggplot2` but with no grouping:

### Setup

```r
library(lubridate) #for graphic
library(ggplot2) # for make_date()


df <- tibble(month = rep(month.name, 40),
             year = rep(c(1961:2000), each = 12),
             PP = runif(12*40) * runif(12*40) * 10) # PP data is random here

print(df, n = 20)
```

```
   month      year     PP
   <chr>     <int>  <dbl>
 1 January    1961 5.42  
 2 February   1961 0.855 
 3 March      1961 5.89  
 4 April      1961 1.37  
 5 May        1961 0.0894
 6 June       1961 2.63  
 7 July       1961 1.89  
 8 August     1961 0.148 
 9 September  1961 0.142 
10 October    1961 3.49  
11 November   1961 1.92  
12 December   1961 1.51  
13 January    1962 5.60  
14 February   1962 1.69  
15 March      1962 1.14  
16 April      1962 1.81  
17 May        1962 8.11  
18 June       1962 0.879 
19 July       1962 4.85  
20 August     1962 6.96 
# … with 460 more rows
```

### Graph

```r
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = make_date(year, factor(month)), y = PP)) + 
  geom_line() +
  xlab("años")
```

[image: img]